# Having issue with intelhaxm install

Tags: android, virtualization

After installing Android studio, while adding virtual device, i get this error

Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer)
I have

- Enabled virtual technology in bios
- when i run sc query intelhaxm, it show me Running (State : 4)
- Selected 'Turn on DEP for all programs and services'
- Checked my processor supports of '
  Intel(R) Virtualization Technology' using Intel untitlity
- Don't have Avast etc installed, Using Windows10 Anniversary Version

I tried all solution as searched on google, 
What i can be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure from what are you writing but is probably Windows 10 [Hyper-V](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/windows_welcome).

You should disable it doing so:

1. Press Windows key + X
2. Select "Program and Features"
3. Click on "Turn Windows features on or off"
4. Uncheck "Hyper-V"

Then you will probably have too restart your machine a couple of times. Then try again to check VT-x support with the Intel Processor Identification Utility. Should work fine now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i was able to fix the issue, When i first installed the visual studio Virtual technology in bios was disabled. i had to uninstall intelhaxm and android studio and then install again and it worked for me.

Comment: Good. It was Hyper-V ?

Comment: Hyper-V was unchecked , i did it at the first step